# Apple Safari still not setting 3rd party domain CORS cookies?

Tags: cookies, safari, cross-domain

After several hours of settings options, headers, cookies on requests and responses in angular and jquery, CORS cookies with Apple Safari still dont work for us.

This page shows the same issue:

http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/credentialedRequest.html

Hitting it with either PC or Mac Safari will not save the cookie and thus always reply:

```
 I do not know you or anyone like you so I am going to mark you with a Cookie :-)
 I do not know you or anyone like you so I am going to mark you with a Cookie :-)
 I do not know you or anyone like you so I am going to mark you with a Cookie :-)
```

Is there still, in 2015, Safari 7 or 8, no way to enable CORS cookies with Safari on a 3rd Party Domain? (Without simulating a visit to that domain?)

Answer (score 15):

Apple has closed all the loopholes and Safari (desktop and mobile) will block all 3rd-party cookies and storage data by default, and will limit 1st-party data based on several factors like tracking signatures, time since last visit, and active usage. *There are no workarounds.*

---

**As of 2016:**

Safari blocks 3rd-party cookies by default. The only way to allow 3rd-party cookies is to effectively make them 1st-party at some point by going directly to that domain, or using a redirect through that domain.

The localstorage and cookies API methods will work but the data can't be read across different domains. Localstorage does *not* work when in Safari Private mode.

**As of 2018:**

Safari's Intelligent Tracking Protection (ITP) now also removes cookies even if set with a 1st-party redirect, using custom whitelists and machine learning to only keep cookies for websites that users have interacted with recently. 1st-party cookies can still be set via 3rd-party Javascript.

**As of 2019**

ITP version 2+ limits 1st-party cookies set by 3rd-party Javascript. Only 1st-party cookies set by the 1st-party domain (either server-side or Javascript) will be kept.

**As of 2020**

ITP version 2.3+ blocks all 3rd-party access of any kind, and all 1st-party cookies/storage is deleted after 7 days from the last interaction with the site. 3rd-party limited access can be granted through the new [Storage Access API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/).

Comment: So just to be sure, even using CORS withCredentials there is no way to set 3rd party cookies in Safari?

Comment: @VladMiller Yes, nothing will be set.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover all the possible states.  If the domain has been visited at some point in the past, will a CORS request from *another* domain be able to update the cookie?

Comment: @user239558 that's already been answered, if you visit the domain used for the cookie then yes you can read/write that cookie on other domains (which is what 3rd party access means).

Comment: I disagree that this is mentioned in the answer.  "Available" or "access" can mean read only, read/write, or even write only.  But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This makes no sense coming from safari especially for HTTP only cookies.. They're here only to keep user credentials... And well actually disables a big layer of security for third party api calls that will require you to expose information to the first party in order to make it work..

Comment: @Tofandel User credentials set by the site are 1st-party cookies set by a 1st-party domain and will be kept up to 7 days so there's no issue there. 3rd-party APIs can still be called by 1st-party code using oauth, or they will need to use the Storage Access API https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/

Comment: Not if the 1st party API providing all features is on another domain (eg app and backend on different domain), it's considered a 3rd party cookie and is completely blocked by this. And if you call oauth from the browser you'll hit the same issue and on each page reload you'll lose auth